# Restrict User Role from Unpublishing Content

Tags: 8, users

I'm attempting to restrict a certain role from being able to unpublish content of a certain content type but I can't get it to work correctly. They need to be able to publish but not unpublish this content.

If "Administer Content" is checked they seem to be given permission to publish/unpublish any content types. If it's unchecked and I attempt to defer to the individual publish/unpublish permissions for that content type they lose the option to use the "Publish" checkbox when editing nodes of that type.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Publish Content](https://www.drupal.org/project/publishcontent) module.